# numpy analog of matplotplotlib contourplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Having a 2d data array `data` and two co-ordinate arrays `x, y` I can plot a contour plot with matplotlib at any given `level`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi), np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = np.sin(xx) * np.sin(yy)
level = 0.5
contour_ = plt.contour(xx, yy, data, levels=[level])
plt.show()
```

Now, I am not really interested in plotting, but rather in position of the contour. For example, I want to see if the contour lies within the x, y domain or 'leaks' outside.

I can get a `path` object containing (x, y) points of the contour by calling

```
contour_path = contour_.collections[0].get_paths()
```

My question is whether there are standard tools to get the same (or analogous) information using only numpy, without matplotlib module. Since no plotting is involved, that would be reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the source code of contour you can find `Cntr`:

```
from matplotlib._cntr import Cntr

x, y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi), np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = np.sin(xx) * np.sin(yy)
level = 0.5

cntr = Cntr(xx, yy, data)
res = cntr.trace(level)
```

res is a list that contains the pathes and the codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the data field, you can find *approximately* where the boundary lies;

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x, y = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi), np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi)

In [3]: xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

In [4]: data = np.sin(xx) * np.sin(yy)

In [5]: scan = np.logical_and(data>0.45, data<0.55)

In [6]: a, b = scan.shape

In [7]: for x in range(a):
        for y in range(b):
                if scan[x,y]:
                        print('({}, {}),'.format(x,y), end='')
   ...:             
(4, 10),(4, 11),(4, 12),(4, 13),(4, 14),(4, 15),(5, 7),(5, 8),(5, 9),
(5, 16),(5, 17),(6, 6),(6, 7),(6, 18),(6, 19),(7, 5),(7, 6),(7, 19),
(8, 5),(8, 20),(9, 5),(9, 20),(10, 4),(10, 20),(11, 4),(11, 20),
(12, 4),(12, 20),(13, 4),(13, 20),(14, 4),(14, 20),(15, 4),(15, 20),
(16, 5),(16, 20),(17, 5),(17, 19),(18, 6),(18, 18),(18, 19),(19, 6),
(19, 7),(19, 17),(19, 18),(20, 8),(20, 9),(20, 10),(20, 11),(20, 12),
(20, 13),(20, 14),(20, 15),(20, 16),(29, 33),(29, 34),(29, 35),
(29, 36),(29, 37),(29, 38),(29, 39),(29, 40),(29, 41),(30, 31),
(30, 32),(30, 42),(30, 43),(31, 30),(31, 31),(31, 43),(32, 30),
(32, 44),(33, 29),(33, 44),(34, 29),(34, 45),(35, 29),(35, 45),
(36, 29),(36, 45),(37, 29),(37, 45),(38, 29),(38, 45),(39, 29),
(39, 45),(40, 29),(40, 44),(41, 29),(41, 44),(42, 30),(42, 43),
(42, 44),(43, 30),(43, 31),(43, 42),(43, 43),(44, 32),(44, 33),
(44, 40),(44, 41),(44, 42),(45, 34),(45, 35),(45, 36),(45, 37),
(45, 38),(45, 39),
```

Of course of make the scan range too small, you won't find many points.

```
In [9]: scan2 = np.logical_and(data>0.49, data<0.51)

In [10]: for x in range(a):
        for y in range(b):
                if scan2[x,y]:
                        print('({}, {}),'.format(x,y), end='')
   ....:             
(4, 12),(5, 17),(7, 19),(9, 20),(12, 4),(17, 5),(19, 7),(20, 9),
(29, 40),(30, 42),(32, 44),(37, 45),(40, 29),(42, 30),(44, 32),
(45, 37),
```